# The type <> must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>.doInBackground(String...)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am currently developing an Android application that is connected to a MySQL database, and I have error with AsyncTask

> The type MenuActivity.DownloadImageTask must implement the inherited
>   abstract method
>   AsyncTask.doInBackground(String...)

```
package com.ilmi.restoran;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.ilmi.restoran.AmbilData.JsonObjectResult;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MenuActivity extends Activity {
    EntitasMakanan entitasmakanan;
    ArrayList<EntitasMakanan> menu = new ArrayList<EntitasMakanan>();
    ListView lv;
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2/menurestoran/menu_services.php";
    String urlpic = "http://10.0.2.2/menurestoran/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_listview);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listmenu);
        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b.containsKey("kategori")){

            String kat=b.getString("kategori");
            Log.d("kat",kat);
            AmbilData ambildata= new AmbilData();
            ambildata.init(MenuActivity.this,jsresult,kat,url);
        }
    }

    public JsonObjectResult jsresult = new JsonObjectResult(){
        @Override
        public void gotJsonObject(JSONObject jobject){
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                JSONArray arraytempat=jobject.getJSONArray("datamenu");
                for (int i =0;i <arraytempat.length();i++){
                    entitasmakanan=new EntitasMakanan();
                    entitasmakanan.setIDmenu(arraytempat.getJSONObject(i).getInt("idmenu"));
                    entitasmakanan.setNamaMenu(arraytempat.getJSONObject(i).getString("nama_menu"));
                    entitasmakanan.setHargaMenu(arraytempat.getJSONObject(i).getString("harga_menu"));
                    entitasmakanan.setDeskripsiMenu(arraytempat.getJSONObject(i).getString("deskripsi_menu"));
                    entitasmakanan.setPicMenu(arraytempat.getJSONObject(i).getString("pic_menu"));
                    menu.add(entitasmakanan);
                }
            }catch (JSONException e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            MenuBaseAdapter datatempat = new MenuBaseAdapter(MenuActivity.this,menu);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override 
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View Arg1, int p, long arg3){
                    String des = menu.get(p).getDeskripsiMenu();
                    String nm = menu.get(p).getNamaMenu();
                    String hrg=menu.get(p).getHargaMenu();
                    String pic=menu.get(p).getPicMenu();
                    tampilkandetail(nm,des,hrg,pic);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    public void tampilkandetail(String nama, String desk, String harga, String pic){
        final Dialog d= new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("detail");
        d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(d.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width=LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height=LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        d.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        ImageView gb = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.picDialog);
        TextView n = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.idNamaMenu);
        TextView h = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.idHarga);
        TextView desc = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.idDeskripsi);
        Button bOk = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.idOk);

        n.setText(nama);
        h.setText(harga);
        desc.setText(desk);
        new DownloadImageTask(gb).execute(urlpic+pic);
        bOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                d.dismiss();
            }
        });
        d.show();
    }
    //help error here: The type MenuActivity.DownloadImageTask must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>.doInBackground(String...)
    public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Bitmap>{
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage){
            this.bmImage=bmImage;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        protected Bitmap doInBackGround(String... urls){
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
            if(result !=null){
                Bitmap bmp2=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result,  72, 72, true);
                bmImage.setImageBitmap(bmp2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: there is no such method called `doInBackGround` however there is one called `doInBackground`

Comment: ... and this is why you should always use `@Override`...

Answer (score 2):

@tyczj is right. You need to change your method name `doInBackGround(String... urls){...}`  
  to this `doInBackground(String... urls){...}` as per the Android docs for the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) class.

Comment: yes, right
thanks for the correction